# Angular ng-repeat table alternating side by side

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new to Angular and have a page that is using the ng-repeat on the table element that is performing the repeat as desired and an example is like below:

[image: Inline]

What I would like to have is alternating every other table would be side by side then continue on the next row below:

[image: Alternating]

Any suggestions would be fantastic...

Answer (score 0):

You can create this structure using bootstrap. this is not related with angularjs.
You can structure your page like this

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 pull-left" ng-repeat="x in tables">
     <table>
       <thead>
       <th>Table#{{$index}}</th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
         your td here...
       </tr>
       </tbody>

     </table>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Hope now you have idea how you can populate this structure

Answer (score 0):

The part of positioning is more into Bootstrapping rather than angular.

Every page is divided into 12 columns. You are just supposed to pick the right amount of columns needed for each table.

for left half , the div class will be col-md-6.The next time you use col-md-6,it will automatically go in the right half of page.

You can read more about it here : [Bootstrap layout and positioning](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)